# Security Filter Chain - having two .authorizeHttpRequest inside one SecurityFilterChain

Tags: spring, spring-security

if I have two .authorizeHttpRequests inside the same securityConfig like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> blahblahblah
            )
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> blahblahblah
            )

        return http.build();
    }

}
```

My question is, does the second .authorizeHttpRequest replaces the first one?

Comment: But I have another question, what is the problem to set all the paths in one ?

Comment: @AndreiLisa Sorry for that. I have modified the question to avoid confusion

Comment: Have you tried in your own this one configuration yet ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a replacement. The second authorize object uses the first authorize object.

The source code ad below

```
private <C extends SecurityConfigurerAdapter<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity>> C getOrApply(C configurer)
        throws Exception {
    C existingConfig = (C) getConfigurer(configurer.getClass());
    if (existingConfig != null) {//If it already existed, return the previous configurer
        return existingConfig;
    }
    return apply(configurer);
}
```